# AngularJs + Laravel проблема с выводом вспомогательной информации

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, laravel

Утречка!

У меня такая проблема, с использованием angular.js я получаю по GET запросу объект новостей,который впоследствии засовываю в ng-repeat. Все бы ничего,но, у каждой новости есть кнопочка "лайк", и ее стиль разный, в зависимости от того, поставлен ли лайк этой новости или нет.

Вопрос: Как мне быть? Просто подгружать данные во view и отдавать их через @foreach, при этом используя какое нибудь if условие, которое проверяет поставлен ли лайк или нет, я не хочу, т.к. если придется подгружать еще данные, это лишнее время + лишний запрос.

Но, если использовать в каждом ng-repeat = это будет слишком затратно? Или это будет равноценно @foreach + проверка с if условием (функцией)?

Можете подсказать, как мне правильно реализовать задуманное? Моя тыковка пока других вариантов не надумала.

Хеелп плс.

Upd/1/

Попытка проверкой в цикле для меня почему-то оборачивается крахом, может, я просто что-то упускаю?

```
<div ng-if="style == 1" ng-repeat="shot in shots">
    News id: @{{ shot.id }}
    <br>
    Liked?: @{{ isLiked(shot.likes) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'}}
</div>
```

Возвращает всегда FALSE.
Хотя, если бы она срабатывала, я бы получал столько false, сколько лайков. Что же делать?

Цикл выглядит так:

```
$scope.isLiked = function (likes) {
     likes.forEach(function(value, key) {
         if(value.user_id === $scope.id) {
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     });
};
```

То что я закидываю в forEach выглядит так:
http://pastebin.com/bMznVTtT

Если сделать просто вывод в этом цикле в консоль, то получаю почему-то это:

```
 Object {id: 1, shot_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: null, updated_at: null}
 Object {id: 2, shot_id: 1, user_id: 2, created_at: null, updated_at: null}
 Object {id: 1, shot_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: null, updated_at: null}
 Object {id: 2, shot_id: 1, user_id: 2, created_at: null, updated_at: null}
```

@_@

Upd/2/

Пока проблему решил так, но я думаю это не самый лучшие вариант.
Перед тем как отдать $shots, добавляю в него дополнительное поле, и в ng-repeat просто его проверяю.

```
$shots = Shot::with('likes', 'user')->get();

foreach($shots as $s) {
    $liked = null;

    if (Auth::check()) {
        $liked = $s->like;
    }

    if ($liked) {
        $liked = true;
    }

    $s->liked = $liked;
}

return $shots;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй вариант намного лучше, т.к. в первом случае вы гоняете по сети весь список лайков, чтобы только найти там себя. Также в случае c флагом liked легко будет в Ангуляре навесить само действие "Лайк" (не придётся оперировать списком, добавляя в него себя при лайке)

Также можно сделать универсальное решение. В Laravel можно повесить [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators) на флаг liked в модели Shot. (Не забываем про массив [$appends](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-serialization))

```
class Shot extends Model
{
    //..
    protected $appends = array('liked');
    // ..
    public function getLikedAttribute()
    {
        if (($userId = Auth::id())) {
            $isLiked = Like::where('shot_id', $this->id)
                    ->where('user_id', $userId)
                    ->first();
            return $isLiked ? true : false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //..
}
```

Далее через ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="shot in shots">
    News id: @{{ shot.id }}<br>
    Liked?: @{{ shot.liked ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'}}
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо,первый раз когда увидел это - подумал,что это гениально и просто, и решение было у меня под носом,но...нет. Во время ng-repeat shot.getLikedAttribute() - undefined.
Если обычный php цикл проводить,то,работать будет. Нельзя ли как то насильно его туда затолкать?

Comment: Узнал теперь о Mutators. :D

Подумал,может проблема была в том что я не указал $casts,но,нет. С указыванием все равно не работает,похоже,нужно что бы на момент ng-repeat там уже было значение.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Синтаксис именования функции мутатора `getLikedAttribute` означает, что он добавит `liked` в ответ. Также, например, чтобы добавить флаг `is_liked`, нужно мутатор назвать `getIsLikedAttribute`

Comment: Я тогда не понимаю в чем проблемка.. 
http://pastebin.com/Q2HUXcKm

А не вариант просто добавлять через класс прям какой-нибудь $attribute, и на __construct повесить обновление его? Тобишь,тоже условие.

Comment: Вы видите по GET-запросу своего контрола liked в выдаче? 
UPD: вынужден поправить себя, не мутатор, а аксессор (Accessor)

Comment: В том то и дело,что его там нету,я поэтому и написал,про добавление аттрибута. Там только $relations, и $attributes.

Вот: http://pastebin.com/9rN68c4b
Я немного обрезал то что получаю,там просто около 12 коллекций.

Comment: Да, забыл про `protected $appends = array('liked');`, обновил ответ

Comment: Александр,Работает,спасибо большое!
Очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете спокойно проверять в цикле условием и в зависимости от условий показывать ту или иную директиву или же добавлять класс к елементу

Comment: У меня какая-то беда с циклами вышла - проверял,он в каждом случае отдавал false. Сейчас приложу код.

Comment: Я обновли пост,описал как смог :D

Comment: а он разве не должен завершить весь цикл? или return останавливает его?

Comment: да не, все нормально в цикле

Comment: тогда я немного не понимаю,можете чуть поподробнее разжевать?